# HTML: How do I simply indent a form?

Tags: html, css

I've searched and searched for what I thought would be a simple find but haven't found anything.  I have this form:

```
<form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="thefile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
    <br />
    <!-- test key -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
</form>
```

I want it indented so it doesn't touch the side of the area it's in, I've tried something like `<div style="text-indent-left:20px">` wrapped around it but didn't phase it.

How do I do I indent the form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following (indented 60 pixels from the left margin)

```css
#form1
{
padding-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<form action="self.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id=form1> 
    <input type="file" name="thefile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
    <br />
    <!-- test key -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the one I used first so selected as answert, but all good.  Just nobody mentioned that those definitions needed to go within <style> </style> tags.

Comment: yes all CSS should be put inside <style></style> (or put into a separate css file and then referred to by the main HTML). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `margin` like so:

```css
.indented{
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="indented"> 
    <input type="file" name="thefile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
    <br />
    <!-- test key -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
</form>
```

However, if you just want the content to be indented, use `padding` like so:

```css
.indented{
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="indented"> 
    <input type="file" name="thefile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
    <br />
    <!-- test key -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
</form>
```